# PayPal PayPalCheckoutSdk get billing adress of payer

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

i'm using the PayPalCheckoutSdk with php8. I can do an order and accept the Order. But I never get the Billing Address.

I used to use this Code
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/
and for completing the Transaction I used this
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/

For our System i need to get the Billing Adress and the Shipping Adress. How can I get it with the PayPal Checkout SDK?
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PayPal processes payments, any information about the funding source -- including the billing address -- is kept private to payers' accounts. This is a reason to prefer using PayPal to make payments on random websites, as that information is kept private by design and cannot be compromised.

Only shipping information (if applicable) is provided in the response.

If you need more billing information from customers, you can collect it yourself. Or if you are a large merchant who habitually collects this information, you can ask PayPal to include it in their API responses and they may consider such a request from a reputable company with established business history, but it will not be there normally.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your Answer. But in Germany it's neccessary to create a Bill and for that I'll need a Billing Address. So If we have to collect it by our self. It's not a problem. Not a really nice Way, but still no problem. Thank you.